# Computing an eigenvalue of $B$ which is expressed in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**The Question:**

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix.Suppose that $A$ has an eigenvalue of 2. Find one eigenvalue of the matrix $3A^2+4A+5I$

**My Solution:**

Since $A$ has an eigenvalue of 2. There exists some vector $v$ such that $Av=2v$

So $3A^2v=3\cdot2Av=12v$ and $4Av=4\cdot2v=8v$

Letting $B=3A^2+4A+5I$ and multiplying by $v$ we get that $Bv=12v+8v+5v=25v$

so $B$ has an eigenvalue of $25$.

**Please advise me if this is not correct!**

Comment: yes, that's correct!

Comment: Okay great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this as a homework question: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $G$ is a polynomial, then $G(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $G(A)$, the polynonial obtained by evaluation at $A$. What you did was right!

Comment: Its a nice property! Was just making sure I wasn't doing anything illegal...

Comment: I encourage you to prove it - it isn't that hard. I'll provide the proof if you get stuck.

Comment: please see answer below!

Answer (score 1):

**Reply to Sean Roberson's Comment:**

So I construct $$G(A)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k A^k $$
where we define $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue of $A  \Rightarrow Av=\lambda v$

We see that $A^n v= A^{n-1} \lambda v $ so it follows that $A^n v = \lambda^n v$

$$G(A) v =\sum_{k=0}^n a_k A^kv = (\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \lambda^k)v=G(\lambda)v$$

and thus if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $G(\lambda)$ is the respective eigenvalue of the polynomial in $A$

Comment: Is this proof satisfactory?

Comment: It is, hence why I upvoted.